# Idiosyncratic Volatility

Tags: finance, fama-french, behavioral-finance

I calculate monthly idiosyncratic volatility as the standard deviation of residuals of a Fama-French regression on daily returns.

Now assume that within these daily returns there is a price hike due to an overreaction of the market. Does this automatically lead to a higher IVOL because the price is irrational and not due to systematic risk factors?

Comment: Do you assume a single short-term event within your FF regression (e.g. the announcement of share repurchases, stock splits,...) or do you think of a long-term persistent overreaction and therefore a permanent misvaluation (starting within a single point of time in the estimation window)?